# Using DNN (DotNetNuke) just to take advantage of the user/roles framework. Better way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, dotnetnuke

I inheritied a DNN project where a small app is stuffed in it using modules.. The only reason for using DNN is so that the management of users/roles is builtin..

I would like to rewrite the app in MVC 3.. Is there any sort of existing UI framework in MVC 3 that handles this ? So I could use that as a starting point ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not going to build using Modules and following the regular extension process of DNN, I would strongly recommend that you not leverage it for your solution.  As over time it will become fragile, or at least have the potential do do so.

There are some third-party ASP.NET User Management solutions out there that will provide a front end for the built in ASP.NET Membership system that might help you with only leveraging users/roles.

Comment: We are using the modules... But not using 96% of DNN so it seems overkill maybe..  Ill look for these 3rd party front ends.. do you know any ?